# In github and eclipse, what does import, push, pull and fetch means?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

In github and eclipse, what does import, push, pull and fetch means? I just want clear answers with more information about it.

Comment: For Git, take a look at this: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: http://git-scm.com/documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse (to be specified in Java) import means importing libraries and classes (Normally your functions defined there!).

In Git,

We can store our files in remote repositories like github. 
So for storing(or pushing) our local repo into a remote repo we use 'push'.
When we need those remote repo into our local repo we have to 'pull'.

These are simplest answers for just getting an idea. Hope this helps